# Google Pay Decrypt Direct Token using .net

Tags: c#, encryption, google-pay

I'm looking for some help decrypting a Google Pay response using .net (c#).  I'm using the JavaScript API and the Direct method https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/guides/setup.  I have the integration working in test and receive an encrypted payload.

The problem is that there doesn't seem to be any .net library that supports decrypting an ECv2 message.  The only library I found is Tink https://github.com/google-pay/tink-jni-examples, however this is using a Java bridge which isn't working for me.

Has anyone done this successfully or written an article on it?

Comment: This question is off-topic for Stack Overflow (request for a resource), but the algorithm that Tink is using is documented at https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/guides/resources/payment-data-cryptography which should allow you to roll your own conforming implementation with a little effort. If you do, consider making it available on GitHub to help others.

Comment: @IanKemp, thanks for the comment, I have been attempting to follow the decryption steps in the Google Docs.  I'm just not familiar with the crypto algorithms

Comment: I wrote a C# sample on how to use BouncyCastle to decrypt these tokens: https://github.com/google-pay/payment-data-cryptography-dotnet (small disclaimer, this is not official: Tink is the library that Google recommends for these purposes)

Comment: @fstanis - I literally game across your library yesterday - I’m working on getting it working with the response I’m getting - most of the issues seem to be around JSON encoding.

Comment: Feel free to file issues on GH if you notice something off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per @fstanis comment, I was able to use https://github.com/google-pay/payment-data-cryptography-dotnet to decrypt the Google Pay data.